# Chef windows how to click a button in a GUI

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

There is a bat file which does some configurations and launch a GUI .In that GUI some buttons need to be clicked to install some other software components .Chef supports these scenarios? How to automate them using Chef? It's a 3rd party installer and has lot of code so deciding it is difficult .Launching a GUI and clicking on a button is easier..vendor has not provided any commands or API..

Answer (score 2):

This is not something Chef does. If the installer doesn't have a headless mode you'll have to look at dedicated Windows automation tools like AutoIt.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried typing app.exe /? to see if the usage was implemented. Also, use procmon (sysinternals) to monitor the parameters passed when executed.